# Group multiple references in one markup element

Tags: msbuild, csproj

we are using some third-party library that have some dependencies that must be referenced from the projects.

So each "csproj" file will have a bunch of "**Reference**" elements that will always be identical.

Is there a way to group this set of elements in one standard element that could be used accross all the csproj files ?

E.g :

```
<ABunchOfReferences>
    <Reference Include="Reference1" />
    <Reference Include="Reference2" />
    <Reference Include="Reference3" />
</ABunchOfReferences>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <ABunchOfReferences/>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

"ABunchOfReferences" would be a kind of macro globally defined and included by all the csprojs that when used would be expanded as 3 "**Reference**" elements.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Why not just define all of the shared references in an import file.

Comment: @Brian: thanks for the idea but I'd like to define more than one group in a file to avoid having a lot of files to maintain and to have to create a new one each time a new bunch of dependencies appears; but this is indeed an acceptable workaround if no other solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your references in an import file, then selectively include them in the main file,

In References.props

```
<ItemGroup>
   <BunchOfReferences Include="Reference1" /> 
   <BunchOfReferences Include="Reference2" /> 
   <BunchOfReferences Include="Reference3" /> 
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <MoreReferences Include="MoreReference1" /> 
   <MoreReferences Include="MoreReference2" /> 
   <MoreReferences Include="MoreReference3" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

...then in the individual project file

```
<Import Project="PathTo\References.props" />

<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="System" />
   <References Include="@(BunchOfReferences)" />
   <References Include="@(MoreReferences)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your "ABunchOfReferences" in a separate file and then include that file inside your ItemGroup like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="PathToFile\yourBunchofReferenceFile" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
 ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at the issue; if I understand well this is an illustration of Brian's solution ?

Comment: Yes he is right. I overlooked that answer and your response to it. To answer your response, you could set the "Condition" attribute in the Reference tag, if you want to conditionally add references.

Comment: Setting a "Condition" would force to pass an additional information from the original msbuild script in order to activate the right condition to only include the subset of references that matches it. It seems quite awkward. I fear I will have to use the multiple files solution.